# UISegmentedControl tint color isn't drawn correctly on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to change the color of a UISegmentedControl on iOS 7. If I change the tint color in the Interface Builder, parts of it are drawn in the tint color, and parts are drawn in the standard blue.

The image ought to make this clearer. I have selected red as the tint color.

[image]

I get the same behaviour on both the simulator and on the device.

If I tap items on the segmented control, they're redrawn in the requested tint color.

If I specify the tint colour in `viewDidLoad`, everything works correctly.

```
[segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Why doesn't the Interface Builder color work?

(It feels like the color property hasn't applied correctly at the time the control is first drawn, but I have no evidence to back that up.)

Comment: I'm having that same issue. It looks like it gets cleared up once one of the other segments are selected. Nice catch on setting it "manually" in `viewDidLoad`. Hopefully this gets fixed in an update to Xcode and/or iOS.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same bizarre behavior. The only workaround I could come up with was to switch the tintColor to something else and then switch it back in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.mySegmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.mySegmentedControl setTintColor:self.view.tintColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write code, there is another workaround that can be done in the storyboard.

Keep the tintColor of the view as the default. The segment control will work then. The downside is that you will have to set the tintColor for each component on your view.